# Is self not equal to the instance variable?

Tags: ruby, oop

Learning Ruby here and this is my first endeavor into OOP and below is my complete code which makes a hash class. I'm having trouble understanding what is happening behind the scenes in the `union` method. When I change `self.to_a.each { |key| joined_set.insert(key) }` to `@store.to_a.each { |key| joined_set.insert(key) }` the hash `joined_set` becomes an array of arrays containing the keys and values of `@store` while it just contains the keys if I use just `self` and not `@store`. How does this discrepancy arise? Is self not equal to the instance variable?

```
class MyHashSet
  def initialize
   @store = {}
  end

 def insert(el)
   @store[el] = true
 end

 def include?(el)
    return true if @store[el]
 false
 end

 def delete(el)
    if @store[el]
      @store.delete(el)
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
   end

  def to_a
    @store.keys
  end

  def union(set2)
     joined_set = self.class.new
     self.to_a.each { |key| joined_set.insert(key) }
     set2.to_a.each { |key| joined_set.insert(key) }
     joined_set
   end

 end
```

Comment: Seems to me like you're cheating if you're using Ruby's `hash` to implement a hash.  Why bother, why not just use Ruby's from the get-go?

Comment: Note that saying `self.` is redundant when referring to instance vars and methods within the class itself.  You can just invoke your `to_a` directly.

Comment: Going through a type of tutorial/class and this is what they are having us do.

Comment: Ruby convention is to eschew an explicit `return`.  The last evaluated expression is returned by default.

Comment: I suspect you're misinterpreting the assignment.  You also seem to be overlooking the fact that hashing works on key/value pairs.  Usually "implementing a hash class" involves writing or utilizing a pre-existing hashing function, which maps keys to integers so the values can be stored in the corresponding location of an array used as backing storage.

Answer (score 1):

The more *specific* reason you're getting different results is that `self.to_a` is equal to `@store.keys`. Why? because that's how you defined `to_a`:

```
def to_a
  @store.keys
end
```

`@store.keys` and `@store.to_a` are very different from each other; `@store` is a ruby `Hash`, and `Hash#to_a` returns an array of arrays, with each subarray being a key-value pair, like `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2]]`; `Hash#keys`, on the other hand, just returns an array of keys.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is not equal to the instance variable.
`self` is equal to the current object, which, in this case, would be the current instance of the MyHashSet class.
so `@store` is an attribute of `self` in this case.

if you had an `attr_accessor` for `@store`, then `@store` would be equal to `self.store`